# Android Studio Starting Error for Mac how can i solve

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHZGa.jpg)

Library>Application Support>no google folder in it. It shows on the internet that it can solve the problem by deleting a few files from the google folder, but there is no such folder in the folder location I mentioned.
I deleted the app and reinstalled it, nothing changed.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

- First, we make hidden files visible by typing

  ```
  "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE ; killall Finder"
  ```

  in the terminal.
- Go to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Android Studio 2020.3.
- Delete the "disable update.txt" file and start the application. It will work flawlessly.